# Uncertain of correct syntax for tx.executeSql for user-entered data

Tags: cordova, storage

In my PhoneGap app, the user types data into form fields, and that data is entered into localStorage, then entered into the webSQL DB like:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data1, data2, data3) VALUES (\"'
 + new_id + '\"' + ', \"' + formdata1Get + '\", \"' + formdata2Get + '\", \"' + formdata3Get + '\")');
```

This works; I can see the DB filled in Chrome's dev tools. However, **how do I then show the entire DB contents?** The following does not work:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id UNIQUE NOT NULL, data1 TEXT NULL, data2 TEXT NULL, data3 TEXT NULL)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data1, data2, data3) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [id, data1, data2, data3]);
```

The error I get is **"Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined"**
That's the id as in:

```
[id, data1, data2, data3]);
```

Reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 0):

Understanding what you have mentioned i have provided a sample code to demonstrate this.Hope it meets your requirement.I have used the rowid column provided by WebSql for the unique field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-serialize-object/2.0.0/jquery.serialize-object.compiled.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test_form" action="" method="post">
    Data 1: <input type="text" name="data1"><br>
    Data 2: <input type="text" name="data2"><br>
    Data 3: <input type="text" name="data3">
    <!--<button onclick="StoreData();">Store into localStorage</button>-->
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Store into localStorage">
</form> 
<button onclick="showValues();">Show WebSql Values</button>
<div id="savedValues"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jsonFormObject;
    var dbInstance;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {      
        dbInstance = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Test DB", 200000);
        dbInstance.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FORMDATA');}); 
        dbInstance.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FORMDATA (data1 TEXT NULL, data2 TEXT NULL, data3 TEXT NULL)')});
    }
    function populateDB(tx) {           
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO FORMDATA (data1, data2, data3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [jsonFormObject.data1, jsonFormObject.data2, jsonFormObject.data3]); 
    }    
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    function showValues() {
        dbInstance.transaction(function(tx){tx.executeSql('SELECT rowid,* FROM FORMDATA', [], querySuccess, errorCB)}, errorCB);
    }   
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        if(len) {
            var html = '<table border=1 width=500 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0><tr><th>Id</th><th>Data 1</th><th>Data 2</th><th>Data 3</th></tr>';
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                html  += '<tr><td>'+results.rows.item(i).rowid + '</td><td>'+results.rows.item(i).data1 + '</td><td>'+results.rows.item(i).data2 + '</td><td>'+results.rows.item(i).data3+'</tr>';            
            }       
            html+='</table>';
            $('#savedValues').html(html);
        }else{
            $('#savedValues').html('No Data found in Database');
        }
    }
    $("#test_form").submit(function(event) {     
          event.preventDefault();
          var formObject = $(this).serializeObject();
           console.log(formObject);       
          // Storing To local Storage
          localStorage.setItem('formObject', JSON.stringify(formObject));     
          // Reading From local Storage
          jsonFormObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formObject'));
          console.log(jsonFormObject);
          //Insert into Websql Database
          dbInstance = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Test DB", 200000);
          dbInstance.transaction(populateDB, errorCB,function(){console.log('inserted successfully')});       
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't this pull from localStorage rather than the database table? In a mobile device, localStorage is not guaranteed to be persistent, but a database is. That's why I want to pull from table and not from localStorage. The only reason I used localStorage was to be able to capture the field data and "Get" it again a few functions further down.

Comment: @Steve the values are now pulled from the table which are displayed in the div named savedValues using SQL Query.Please clarify if i am wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your time andhelp! Are you able to do this without Jquery? I'm not using any frameworks. Why doesn't this work written like this: function showValues() { tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM FORMDATA', [], querySuccess, errorCB; } ? Thanks!

Comment: @Steve It is due to the reason every SQL query should be within a database transaction instance.in this case the tx variable holds the reference to the database transaction which is being done.
Jquery is used here for serializing the HTML form data using the serialize object plugin which has a dependency on Jquery.It is OK to use Jquery library in your Phonegap projects.